# Custom spelling on Word 2010,2013,2016 with a VSTO add-in and C#, is it possible?

Tags: c#, vsto

there.

We have developed MS Word plugin which does spelling and grammar checker in the document.

I have an application-level add-in that, amongst other functionality, gives the user the option to use our own set of rules when checking spelling and grammar instead of the dictionary currently selected in Word. A user will be able to configure the application to use our own checking.

If it's possible, we'd like to "mark" the errors the same way Word does it, with a red wavy underscore for spelling errors, green for grammatical errors, and so on. Is that possible? I've seen that there is a SpellingErrors property in the Range class but I imagine that uses Word's own spell checking. Is there a way for us to substitute it with our own, or, even better, a way to just "underscore with a wavy red line" a Range?

Of course, there's no way both Word's checking and our own will be active at the same time, we make sure of it.

Comment: No, it's not possible for third-parties to use Word's internal spell and grammar check marking (wavy lines).

Comment: @CindyMeister That's too bad. Well, thanks for the information.